# How to find the ajax status with jQuery 1.2.6

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using jQuery 1.2.6 (I know it's old, but I don't have a choice) I need to check the status of my ajax calls. I either want to use:

`statusCode`, or I could even use `error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)`, except that `textStatus`, `errorThrown` and `statusCode`, aren't in my jQuery version.

Basically what I have to do, is know if the ajax call was aborted, or had an error for another reason. Any ideas how I can do this?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what's stopping you using newer versions? Plugins that break, or something?

Comment: @JamWaffles sometime corporation does not want you to use the latest version. We are still in 1.4 and we can't use the latest one.

Comment: Ah ok. I don't/haven't worked for anyone, so I wouldn't know :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could get the status text from the error callback:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/foo",
    dataType: "text",
    error: function(obj){
        alert(obj.status + "\n" + obj.statusText);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jnXQ4/

you can also get it from the complete callback if the request resulted in an error.

Edit: the ajax request also returns the XMLHttpRequest which you can then bind events to, though I'm not sure how cross-browser it is.

```
var request = $.ajax(options);
request.onabort = function(){
  alert('aborted');
}
```

Comment: I was trying to use textStatus, errorThrown which are not supported in the version I'm using.

Comment: the actual names of the object properties may vary from browser to browser, keep that in mind.